# ssh key has the file path as the name

Tags: ssh, 20.04

When ssh'ing into my Ubuntu server, I get this

> Enter passphrase for key '/home/ben/.ssh/id_rsa':

However, I don't know why the key is named this way. Is there a way I can change this name or make a new key with a name, like ben@bmwlaptop (user Ben on my laptop named bmwlaptop)? If this explanation isn't very good, I want it to look like this:

> Enter passphrase for key 'ben@bmwlaptop':

Comment: You may have to change the (source) code for the `ssh` binary.

Comment: so i had ubuntu already on my computer once, and the ssh was how I wanted it. however, I nuked that version and reinstalled and started fresh and now its this way. idk if that helps. does the login for everyone else look like mine?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke

Comment: You can *name* the keypair files anything you wish - the defaults for an RSA keypair are `id_rsa` / `id_rsa.pub` but `ssh-keygen` accepts a `-f` parameter to customize that. However afaik the ssh client will still show the full path. If you used to see something like `ben@bmwlaptop` I suspect that was because your previous installation was configured to use an *agent* (such as `ssh-agent`) to unlock / manage your keys, and it was **that** that was prompting you for the passphrase, rather than the `ssh` client itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the SSH keypair with the file name desired

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/ben@bmwlaptop
```

You can also rename the existing keypair and still use it.  Simply rename the files

```
mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/ben@bmwlaptop
mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/ben@bmwlaptop.pub
```

To use the keypair, you can specify the file explicity with the `-i` option

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ben@bmwlaptop localhost
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ben/.ssh/ben@bmwlaptop':
```

To use the keypair automatically, update the `IdentityFile` setting for SSH

```
cat >> ~/.ssh/config << EOF
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ben@bmwlaptop
EOF
ssh localhost
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ben/.ssh/ben@bmwlaptop':
```